# Jolokia / JMX authentication in Javascript app

Tags: java, javascript, json, api, jmx

I develop a javascript-based frontend for JMX / jolokia backend. Basically, the tool should be a prettier html5-based JConsole for people, who don't code in Java.

#### My question is, how am I supposed to authenticate users trying to read / update data from JMX?

Should I create some kind of Node.js-based proxy that would manage sessions, user authentication and pass queries between HTML5 frontend and JMX or use JMX authentication?

#### I've come up with 2 solutions:

1. Ajax request -> Node.js auth -> Jolokia -> JMX -> Jolokia -> Node.js -> Ajax response
2. Ajax request -> Jolokia -> JMX -> Jolokia -> Ajax request

In ***1.*** Node.js is transparent, ie. does not change requests passed to Jolokia and returned from it.

As a javascript and frontend dev I have experience with backend technologies such as Ruby, Node.js and most popular PHP frameworks as well, but not as much experience with Java and, to be honest, I don't know which practice is better. Is there any 3rd option perhaps?

I think it's important to stress the fact that communication is XHR / JSON based and I'm using Angular.js as a MVC framework here. I could, for instance, create a Angular.js service that will utilize JS library from Jolokia.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Basic Authentication directly with Jolokia's [JavaScript](http://www.jolokia.org/reference/html/clients.html#js-request) library if you secure your Jolokia Agent accordingly. I.e. if you use the Jolokia WAR-Agent you can [set it up](http://www.jolokia.org/reference/html/agents.html#agent-war-security) to use J2EE security. For the other types of agents exist similar mechanisms.

For accessing JMX directly you need a proxy for sure, since you won't be able to access JMX directly from within JavaScript anyway (with or without security).

My recommendation is for option 2. above, but please use the newest Snapshot releases (1.1.2-SNAPSHOT, 1.1.2 is soon to be released) because it contains some important fixes for CORS access.

But before you go to far, do you know [hawt.io](http://hawt.io) ? This is probably quite similar to your planned project